# The application hung when a simple react code was run

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating a simple react app and when the Form.js is added to the components folder, the  app is no longer loading and getting the error, Error code: RESULT_CODE_HUNG.

Following is my App.js file.

```
import React from "react";
import Header from './components/Header';
import Form from './components/Forms';
import './App.css';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="app-wrapper">
        <div>
          <Header/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <Form/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Following is the Form.js file

```
import React from "react";

const Form = () =>{
    return(
        <Form>
            <input 
             type="text"
             placeholder="Enter a Todo.." 
             className="task-input"/>
            <button className="button-add" type="submit">
                Add
            </button>
        </Form>
    );
};

export default Form;
```

Following is the Header.js.

```
import React from "react";

const Header = () =>{
    return(
        <div className="header">
            <h1>Todo List</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Header;
```

The index.js file looked like below.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById('root'));
```

Can someone please let me know the reason for not loading this.
The app loaded without an issue when only the Header is used.

[image]

Comment: what is in the Form component?

Comment: I have put the content of the Form.js

Comment: I think I got the error... It is because, inside the const Form = () =>{, I have put <Form></Form>. which creates an infinite loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use a `<form>` tag instead of rendering the component itself.

```js
import React from "react";

const Form = () =>{
    return(
        <form>
            <input 
             type="text"
             placeholder="Enter a Todo.." 
             className="task-input"/>
            <button className="button-add" type="submit">
                Add
            </button>
        </form>
    );
};

export default Form;
```

Or if you are using a form from another source you should `import` it correctly.